# Migration problem for Material UI chips not to be rounded by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, migration

I am trying to migrate Material UI v4 to Material UI v5. There is a weird behavior that the chip component does. Normally chips should be rounded by default. However, when I add onClick function it makes chips square. When I remove the onClick function, it turns rounded. Can anyone know why this is happening?

> <Chip
> icon={icon}
> disabled={!showAnalytics}
> style={style}
> label={name}
> onClick={() => onChipClick(id)}
> />